# Is there a way to refresh WPF DataGrid using ObservableCollection and MVVM without informing ItemsSource collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

This is my first question so I'll do my best.

I'm trying to get a simple WPF DataGrid control to be "refreshed" using ObservableCollection and MVVM as the numerous tutorials on the web explain.

In context, these are my model clases:

(PersonViewModel.cs)

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _id;
    private int _idAddress;
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private string _address;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._id)
            {
                this._id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int IdAddress
    {
        get { return this._idAddress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._idAddress)
            {
                this._idAddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._name)
            {
                this._name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return this._age; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._age)
            {
                this._age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get { return this._address; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._address)
            {
                this._address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String caller = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

(AddressViewModel.cs)

```
public class AddressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _id;
    private string _street;
    private int _number;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._id)
            {
                this._id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Street
    {
        get { return this._street; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._street)
            {
                this._street = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Number
    {
        get { return this._number; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._number)
            {
                this._number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String caller = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a representation of the database model (cannot upload pic < 10 posts)

### Address

Id
Street
Number

### Person

Id
IdAddress
Name
Age
Address ---> this property concatenates Street and Number of Address entity.

So, as you can see, it's a very simple example. Just a proof-of-concept. Problem is, whenever I try to add a new entity to the database (through Entity Framework 6 and LINQ) I must inevitably add that ViewModel entity to the DataGrid's data context.

This is the code working as of today:

```
public static Person CreatePerson(PersonViewModel personVM)
{
    var person = new Person
    {
        IdAddress = personVM.IdAddress,
        Name = personVM.Name,
        Age = personVM.Age
    };

    try
    {
        using (var context = new OCDemoContext())
        {
            context.Database.Connection.Open();
            context.Person.Add(person);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return person;
}
```

As you can see, the need here is to show in DataGrid a column that concatenates two properties of Address database entity: Street and Number, and giving that value to Address property of PersonViewModel class to show as a column in the DataGrid.

The code that adds the entity to the DataGrid itemssource collection after the insert to the database:

```
        // Add to the database
        PersonsGateway.CreatePerson(personVM);

        // Update view on DataGrid's itemssource collection
        ViewModel model = this.xGrid.DataContext as ViewModel;

        model.Persons.Insert(0, personVM);
```

XAML as:

```
<Window x:Class="OCDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OCDemo">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="xViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="xGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource xViewModel}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="xDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Age}" Header="Age"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" Header="Address"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Persons = PersonsGateway.RetrievePersons();
    }
}
```

And T4 .tt file updated as [MSDN - Updating code generation for data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/data/jj574514) explains.

So, it is possible to depend only on adding the entity to the database and not to always add the entity to the itemssource collection after that on a ObservableCollection scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Change your view model to the following

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
        Persons.AddRange(PersonsGateway.RetrievePersons().ToList());
    }
}
```

Its important to create the observable collection once and not recreate it, to rely on change notifications, so create it and then use the standard methods to manage it.

Comment: I did what you suggested. No changes. My goal is to add the new instance of PersonViewModel to the database through EF methods directly and that action updates ViewModel on UI. Is this possible at all? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I should of suggested that instead of this code

```
    PersonsGateway.CreatePerson(personVM);

    ViewModel model = this.xGrid.DataContext as ViewModel;

    model.Persons.Insert(0, personVM);
```

you should do

```
PersonsGateway.CreatePerson(personVM);

ViewModel model = this.xGrid.DataContext as ViewModel;

model.Persons.Add(personVM);
```

Comment: In fact, what I'm tryin' to do is don't use `ViewModel model = this.xGrid.DataContext as ViewModel;

model.Persons.Add(personVM);` nor `ViewModel model = this.xGrid.DataContext as ViewModel;

    model.Persons.Insert(0, personVM);`, just the `PersonsGateway.CreatePerson(personVM);`...or I MUST totally 1.- insert entity to the database and then 2.- update model? cheers Phil

Comment: The PersonsGateway is your EF adapter right, its disconnected from the ObservableCollection.

You should have a reference to your parent VM in which the Persons collection exists so it should be easy that as soon as you know you've successfully created the person just add it, either that or refresh the view entirely (rebuilding, but then why have an ObservableCollection)

Comment: Sorry, I should of read your initial question thoroughly, what you are really asking is can you get an ObservableCollection to act like a DataSet used to, where you basically bind the data adapter to it. I don't think you can do this

Comment: What you'd normally do here is call your service/repo and it would return a constructed Person VM which you'd then Add to your ObservableCollection

Comment: Exactly. That is I was trying to do. Rely in just the Gateway update. I must understand better the ObservableCollection concept and application. Thanks anyway Phil :)